# Excel, match a minimum of 3 and a max of 5 numbers for each row and add the number of cells containing the match displaying in G2 along each row

Tags: python, excel, vba

Column B thru F is the numbers assigned to each name in (My Main List)  down 5 rows. Rows can be longer but in this example I have it at 5. Columns I thru M I have numbers entered (the entry list) down 10 rows but can be longer. I need see how many matches in each row of of my main list (B2:F2) matches all the cells along each row in my entry list (I2:M2) and Matching at least 3 out of 5 numbers.

Then each match it finds it increments and Displays totals at column G2 and down along each row it matches.

In this Example:
I have tried using this python code but it counts all the numbers that matches B2:F2.

```py
import openpyxl

def count_matches_in_excel():
# Load the Excel file
  workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('MyMatches.xlsx')
  sheet = workbook.active

# Define the range of rows to match (B2:F2 down 10 rows)
  match_range = sheet['B2':'F6']

# Define the range of rows to count matches (I2:M2 down 20 rows)
  count_range = sheet['I2':'M10']

# Initialize the count for each rowcls
  counts = [0] * 20

# Iterate over each row in the match range
  for row in match_range:
    # Iterate over each cell in the row
    for cell in row:
        value = cell.value
        
        # Iterate over the count range for the corresponding row
        for target_row in count_range:
            # Iterate over each cell in the target row
            for target_cell in target_row:
                target_value = target_cell.value
                
                # Check if the values match
                if value == target_value:
                 
                    # Increment the count for the corresponding row
                    row_index = match_range.index(row)
                    counts[row_index] += 1
                    
                

 #Write the counts to the cells starting from G2 down 10 rows
        for i, count in enumerate(counts):
         sheet.cell(row=2 + i, column=7).value = count

# Save the modified Excel file
  workbook.save('example_Matches.xlsx')
```

```
A       B      C      D      E     F      G      H     I      J      K     L       M
```

| Name | Row1 | Row2 | Row3 | Row4 | Row5 | Total |  | Row6 | Row7 | Row8 | Row9 | Row10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 16 | 21 | 29 | 32 | 38 | 11 |  | 29 | 32 | 38 | 4 | 5 |
| Bob | 1 | 3 | 18 | 4 | 6 | 17 |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| Nancy | 10 | 14 | 19 | 23 | 25 | 4 |  | 18 | 19 | 23 | 21 | 35 |
| Tom | 18 | 21 | 24 | 32 | 35 | 10 |  | 1 | 21 | 24 | 20 | 35 |
| Mike | 1 | 7 | 22 | 23 | 35 | 12 |  | 16 | 32 | 3 | 38 | 5 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 10 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 29 | 2 | 38 | 4 | 32 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 7 | 23 | 22 | 35 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 |

This is an Example of preferred way I would like displayed total in column G2:

```
A       B      C      D      E     F       G     H     I      J      K      L      M
```

| Name | Row1 | Row2 | Row3 | Row4 | Row5 | Total |  | Row6 | Row7 | Row8 | Row9 | Row10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 16 | 21 | 29 | 32 | 38 | 3 |  | 29 | 32 | 38 | 4 | 5 |
| Bob | 1 | 3 | 18 | 4 | 6 | 3 |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| Nancy | 10 | 14 | 19 | 23 | 25 |  |  | 18 | 19 | 23 | 21 | 35 |
| Tom | 18 | 21 | 24 | 32 | 35 | 2 |  | 1 | 21 | 24 | 20 | 35 |
| Mike | 1 | 7 | 22 | 23 | 35 | 1 |  | 16 | 32 | 3 | 38 | 5 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 10 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 29 | 2 | 38 | 4 | 32 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 7 | 23 | 22 | 35 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 |

Any help is very Appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for VBA or Python code?

Comment: btw, Bob's total should be 3 if I were right.

Comment: Your right made a typo for Bob.  I would like python but I will take VBA too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say if python was required, so in case you wanted something simpler adn Excel formula of
`=SUM(--BYROW($I$2:$M$10,LAMBDA(row,SUM(XLOOKUP(B2:F2,row,SEQUENCE(1,5,1,0),0))>=3)))` would do the job, although as taller_ExcelHome pointed out your dummy data for Bob is wrong

[image]

Comment: Ya your right I did a typo with Bob.  I'm testing with this formula Thanks.

Comment: Using 2021 Excel.  Getting #NAME? error. Made sure formula is correct.

Comment: Ahh sorry, you need an MS 365 version for some of those formulas to work (it's probably the BYROW or LAMBDA that's the issue). I'll throw together a quick PowerQuery script that will work in Excel 2021.

Comment: Thanks Ben your answer was useful. Using MS 2021 Excel, I got another formula: =SUM(IF(MMULT(SIGN(IFERROR(XMATCH($I$2:$M$10,B2:F2),0)),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS($I$2:$M$10),,,0))>=3,1))

Answer (score 0):

If OP is looking for Python code, `pandas` is a better approach.

```py
import pandas as pd
data1 = {
    'Row6': [29, 1, 18, 1, 16, 1, 29, 1, 1],
    'Row7': [32, 2, 19, 21, 32, 2, 2, 7, 2],
    'Row8': [38, 3, 23, 24, 3, 3, 38, 23, 3],
    'Row9': [4, 4, 21, 20, 38, 4, 4, 22, 4],
    'Row10': [5, 6, 35, 35, 5, 10, 32, 35, 6]
}
data2 = {
    'Name': ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Nancy', 'Tom', 'Mike'],
    'Row1': [16, 1, 10, 18, 1],
    'Row2': [21, 3, 14, 21, 7],
    'Row3': [29, 18, 19, 24, 22],
    'Row4': [32, 4, 23, 32, 23],
    'Row5': [38, 6, 25, 35, 35]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2['Total'] = df2.apply(lambda df2_row: 
    df1.apply(lambda df1_row: 
        (df2_row.iloc[1:].isin(df1_row).sum() >= 3).sum(), 
        axis=1).sum(), axis=1)
print(df2)
```

Output

```
    Name  Row1  Row2  Row3  Row4  Row5  Total                                                                  
0    Joe    16    21    29    32    38      3                                                                  
1    Bob     1     3    18     4     6      3                                                                  
2  Nancy    10    14    19    23    25      0                                                                  
3    Tom    18    21    24    32    35      2                                                                  
4   Mike     1     7    22    23    35      1
```

Comment: Do u revise the code w/ pd?

Comment: pls update op with your new code.

Comment: Update OP with your expected output. It is helpful for understanding the issue.